# Getting "No file or variants found for asset" found error on my asset

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am getting this attached error when I try and run my app. Any ideas? 
(Below)

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM J200Y in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: assets/credentials.json.
```

I have checked the yaml file and the formatting seems to be fine. I am at a loss as want the issue is. (Also, below)

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - assets/credentials.json
```

Comment: your code is not properly indented . `assets` and `- assets/cr...`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check identation of assets. Generally it should have 3 spaces from start of new line.

```
assets:
 - assets/credentials.json // <-- count three spaces from start
```

Comment: it looks like 4 spaces in the official tutorial code: https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/examples/layout/lakes/step6/pubspec.yaml

Comment: **indentation**

Answer (score 192):

In my case, the problem was that I was missing slash `/`.

At first, I have added my icons path as below.

```
  assets:
      - assets/icons
```

I solve the issue by adding as slash `/` to the end of the path as below:

```
  assets:
      - assets/icons/
```

Answer (score 25):

I was facing the same problem, and I had two mistakes:

1. I created the "images" folder inside the "lib" folder, and it should be outside the lib folder, it should be in the app root folder. [image]
2. It should be three spaces from the starter line as @Darshan said

   > -assets/credentials.json // <-- count three spaces from start

   It should appear a grey line, like this

   [image]

Comment: Just an FYI that's 4 spaces from the start of the new line (`assets:` is itself 2 spaces from the start) of the line

Answer (score 6):

*there are 2 possibility*

0. Folder/file missing in your project directory
1. Missing **"/"** in the end of folder/file name in **pubspec.yaml** file

Answer (score 2):

try copying the file manually not using VS-Code or Android studio. don't use drag/drop.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, I was able to fix it by using only the name of directory created in the projects root folder, instead of also including the file i was trying to point to.

```
assets:
  - images/
```

is what worked for me instantly, just point to the whole dir and specify the file name in ImageAssets object.

Comment: James code did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

You need mention as
assets:
- assets/icons/

in pubspec.yaml

Comment: I was facing the same. I was missing the slash at the end of icons.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to enter filename as such:

```
flutter:   assets:
    - lib/assets/logo.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and I had two mistakes:
When I add lib in assets then I solve my problem.

flutter:

```
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - lib/images/background.jpg
```