# Flutter Error "No file or variants found for assets/translation"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

My Flutter app failed to build and it shows error "No file or variants found for assets/translation".

My pubsec.yaml as follows

```
  assets:
   - assets/
   - assets/translations
```

my directory as follows
[image]

Kindly help me fix . thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "No file or variants found for asset" found error on my asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657146/getting-no-file-or-variants-found-for-asset-found-error-on-my-asset)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, neither as question nor as answer; for directory structure that's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error after some research that I was missing "/" at the end of the entry in pubsec.yaml file.

please see the screen shot below for the corrected code

```
  assets:
   - assets/
   - assets/translations/
```